# How to design classes with constructor taking a std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initializer-list

When classes have a constructor overload taking a `std::initializer_list`, this overload will take precedence even if other constructor overloads are seemingly a better match. This problem is described in detail in Sutter's [GotW#1](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/), part 2, as well as Meyers' [*Effective Modern C++*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do), Item 7.

The classic example of where this problem manifests itself is when brace-initializing a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2};
// Is this a vector with elements {1, 2}, or a vector with a single element 2?
```

Both Sutter and Meyers recommend to avoid class designs where a `initializer_list` constructor overload can cause ambiguities to the programmer.

Sutter:

> Guideline: When you design a class, avoid providing a constructor that
>   ambiguously overloads with an initializer_list constructor, so that
>   users won’t need to use ( ) to reach such a hidden constructor.

Meyers:

> As a result, it’s best to design your constructors so that the
>   overload called isn’t affected by whether clients use parentheses or
>   braces. In other words, learn from what is now viewed as an error in
>   the design of the std::vector interface, and design your classes to
>   avoid it.

But neither of them describe *how* `vector` should have been designed to avoid the problem!

So here's my question: **How should have `vector` been designed to avoid ambiguities with the `initializer_list` constructor overload (without losing any features)?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would take the same approach that the standard took with `piecewise_construct` in `pair` or `defer_lock` in `unique_lock`: using tags on the constructor:

```
struct n_copies_of_t { };
constexpr n_copies_of_t n_copies_of{};

template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class vector {
public:
    vector(std::initializer_list<T>);
    vector(n_copies_of_t, size_type, const T& = T(), const A& = A());
    // etc.
};
```

That way:

```
std::vector<int> v{10, 20}; // vector of 2 elems
std::vector<int> v2(10, 20); // error - not a valid ctor
std::vector<int> v3(n_copies_of, 10, 20); // 10 elements, all with value 20.
```

Plus, I always forget if it's 10 elements of value 20 or 20 elements of value 10, so the tag helps clarify that.

Comment: Cool! I was not aware they had addressed the problem in other parts of the standard library.

Comment: This approach has the advantage that the constructor overloads are usable for both heap and stack allocation.

Comment: @EmileCormier: You can use those overloads for heap and stack allocations either way... can't you?  I can't think of anything preventing it.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think you're right. However, with my proposed solution, it would involve invoking the copy/move constructor. Whereas with Barry's solution, the container would be directly initialized from the constructor arguments.

Comment: Is there a reason to have the tag at the front? (Maybe, for consistency with functions that have parameter packs?) If not, why not `vector(size_type, copies_of_t, T const&);`? (Btw, C++11 removed the default argument for the `const value_type&`, probably because you can write a ctor that value-initializes N elements without requiring copyability.)

Comment: @dyp I like that even better! `vector<int> v(10, copies_of, 20);` is pretty unambiguous!

Comment: @dyp: I guess that from a stylistic point of view, you can consider the tag as being an extension of the function's name.

Comment: One disadvantage with this approach is that it pollutes the namespace with tag types. It's too bad this couldn't work in a terse fashion with the tag types being nested types within `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, one possible way (and not one I advocate) to avoid the ambiguity is to use static factory methods as a means to isolate the `initializer_list` constructor from the others.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    static Container with(size_t count, const T& value)
    {
        return Container(Tag{}, count, value);
    }

    Container(std::initializer_list<T> list) {/*...*/}

private:
    struct Tag{};
    Container(Tag, size_t count, const T& value) {/*...*/}
};
```

Usage:

```
auto c1 = Container<int>::with(1, 2); // Container with the single element '2'
auto c2 = Container<int>{1, 2}; // Container with the elements {1, 2}
```

This static factory approach is reminiscent of how objects are [allocated and initialized in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html).  The nested `Tag` struct is used to ensure that the `initializer_list` overload is not viable.

---

Alternatively, the `initializer_list` constructor can be changed to a static factory method, which allows you to keep the other constructor overloads intact:

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    static Container with(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    {
        return Container(Tag{}, list);
    }

    Container(size_t count, const T& value) {/*...*/}

private:
    struct Tag{};
    Container(Tag, std::initializer_list<T> list) {/*...*/}
};
```

Usage:

```
auto c1 = Container<int>{1, 2}; // Container with the single element '2'
auto c2 = Container<int>::with({1, 2}); // Container with the elements {1, 2}
```

Comment: This approach has the disadvantage that the "static-ified" overloads can't be used to initialize a container on the heap.

Comment: I meant to say that the "static-ified" overloads can't be used to **directly** initialize a heap-allocated container. I could always to this: 
`auto heapContainer = new Container(Container::with(1,2));` (which could incur a slight performance penalty).